# Where are my Pages documents?

Tags: time-machine, restore, pages

Recently replaced iMac hard drive through recall program. Used Time Machine/Seagate Backup Drive. Everything seems to be restored but my Pages documents. How do I find them?

Comment: If you're using recent OSX and Pages, were you documents stored to the cloud by default?

Answer (score 1):

What about looking for files with the pages extension (.pages) in spotlight?

Open spotlight (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> ) and type: **.pages**

If you see a file popping up, hold <kbd>Command</kbd> an click on it. The file's location will then be opened in finder.